# Show file in the folder in PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside2

I was wondering, is there the possibility to show the  file inside the folder with this call? just see the file, but select the folder

```
self.directory = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory()
self.pathField.append(self.directory)
fileList = os.listdir(self.directory)
```

There's a similar question, but I've already tried and it didn't work for me

screenshot

[image]

Comment: Could you explain yourself better? PyQt or PySide2?

Comment: When the dialog appear, I see just the folder, but not the file. Like a folder full of img, I see the folder but if I open it, it's empty

Comment: Okay, but that code is made to select folders, what I understand is that you want to be able to enter the folders and see the files, but only select folders. I am right?

Comment: Yes, just see the files to check if it's the right folder

Comment: I just tried a standard code and I can see inside the folders, you could show the code you are using, by the way it is not getdirectory, but getExistingDirectory.

Comment: I have a folder with img inside and if i open it, I can't see the img, like if it's empty

Comment: You could show images with the windows explorer and another with the QFileDialog.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Can you explain me better?

Comment: I want proof of what it indicates is correct, many times they say one thing and the reality is another, so I ask you to show evidence, an image with the windows explorer and another one executing your code to see the differences.

Comment: Ah, yeah ok, why not. I added a link in the question and the code is the one I've already posted

Comment: @eyllanesc hey mate, after you asked for the img you're vanished?